# Read file which name contains hangul from console

Tags: c#, cjk

code

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace letstest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
            File.OpenRead(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

There is a.txt and 아.txt in same folder.
When I write a.txt, it works well.
But when I write 아.txt, it throws.

I have not checked what is the value of `fileName`, but I typed "아.txt" as shown in input/output below:

```
아.txt

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at letstest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\nasoo\source\repos\letstest\letstest\Program.cs:line 10
```

I want to make my program that can read file which name contains hangul. How to solve this?

Comment: Both Windows and Linux support that character in file names. I can't reproduce your problem https://dotnetfiddle.net/IwQy2y, please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: are you sure there is no other characters read by Console.Readline

Comment: You say you have an error when _writing_ to a file, but you don't show any writing code or the exact input you've used for that API call.

Comment: The problem is that the console and your application use different character sets. Because the Asian character cannot be encoded correctly, it is replaced with a question mark which is not allowed in file names. You have to solve the problem by changing the character set of the console (in Windows) and/or setting the Console.InputEncoding appropriately.